# How to flag duplicate answer for same question?

Tags: support

For a question there are multiple answer present among those same answer repeat by two users.

How to flag second answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag one of the answers using *in need of moderator intervention* and explain it repeats what already given from another answer, possibly pointing out which answer, exactly.
Moderators will delete the answer, if necessary.

Keep in mind that there could be two users giving a similar answer in a 5 minutes time frame; this could happen, and there isn't much that can be done.
If you see an answer that is a carbon copy of another one, flag it even if it was given by the same user.